# Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

when i run this code
public class test2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      String podName = "xrdpprocan";
      String namespace = "default";
      String master = "https://my_ip_adress"; 

      Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(master).withTrustCerts(true).build();
      try (final KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config)) {

        String log = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withName(podName).getLog(true);
        System.out.println("Log of pod " + podName + " in " + namespace + " is:");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println(log);

      } catch (KubernetesClientException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
}
```

i get this Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring.

Comment: Are you running the code from inside a pod, or externally from the cluster?

Comment: If you're inside a pod and if somebody else is administering your cluster, they might have disabled the Kubernetes feature that provides a service account token to your pod.

Comment: when i do kubectl get serviceAccount i get  NAME          SECRETS   AGE
                                                                     build-robot   1         3d
                                                                        default       1         10d
                                                                        fabric8       1         2d

Comment: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token there is no file or directory

Comment: I am running the code externally from the cluster

Comment: If that token file exists (as others have pointed out, it may be disabled) it is inside the container not on a cluster node.  You're fetching the logs from the app, you could just log the token and grab it that way--that may make visible elsewhere, too.

Answer (score 3):

**Where is the problem:** The current type of your client configuration is incomplete, you are missing the client authentication settings/data part.

Please be aware, when you are running your code from outside the cluster
(this type of client configuration is called **out-of-cluster client configuration**) you need to specify explicitly a bare minimum for successful connection to Kubernetes control-plane from outside.

1. Kubernetes Master URL
2. At least one method for **user authentication**, can be any of:

- client certificates
- bearer tokens
- HTTP basic auth

**You see the problem ?** - you have specified none of these from the second condition for `>> user <<` authentication (this is a key word here: `user`)

**Right now** Java Kubernetes client falls back into **Service account** based authentication strategy, thinking you are not human but robot (Pod running in context of Service Account).

Putting it technically, client is resolving now to the last resort option:

> [KUBERNETES_AUTH_TRYSERVICEACCOUNT](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/b68aa7ea982a4eb2c90314716ea45e08600fd265/kubernetes-tests/pom.xml#L143)

(**4th** on the list of fabric8io/kubernetes-client supported configuration option, check below)

which involves reading in service account token placed into the filesystem inside Pod's container at following path:

> /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

---

Officially [fabric8io/kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#configuring-the-client) java client supports the following ways of configuring the client:

> This will use settings from different sources in the following order
> of priority:
>
> - System properties
> - Environment variables
> - Kube config file
> - Service account token & mounted CA certificate     <== you client code tries this
>
> System properties are preferred over environment variables. The
> following system properties & environment variables can be used for
> configuration

**The easiest solution** is to rely on `Kube config file` option to access cluster from outside, e.g.:

```
public class KubeConfigFileClientExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException {

    // file path to your KubeConfig

    String kubeConfigPath = System.getenv("HOME") + "/.kube/config";

    // loading the out-of-cluster config, a kubeconfig from file-system
    ApiClient client =
        ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(new FileReader(kubeConfigPath))).build();

    // set the global default api-client to the in-cluster one from above
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

    // the CoreV1Api loads default api-client from global configuration.
    CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();

    // invokes the CoreV1Api client
    V1PodList list =
        api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
      System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Full code sample can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/KubeConfigFileClientExample.java).